# how to take input from user and insert it in a arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

i have a Student class and my arraylist is of type student .now,how do i take input from user and insert it in my arraylist?

Comment: [First Google How to Take Input in Java](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-take-input-from-user) , then Store each input to the Object's attributes and finally add it to list !!

Comment: please show us what you already tried and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: By writing the code to do so. You can use a Scanner instance or JOptionPane boxes for the input, and the .add method to add the information into the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
   ----------------------- Main Class File --------------------
   public class TestingClass {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of students detail : ");
        int numberOfInputs = input.nextInt();

        ArrayList<Student> StudentList = new ArrayList<Student>();


        for( int i=0;  i < numberOfInputs ; i++){
            System.out.println("Please enter Name : ");
            String name = input.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter Address : ");
            String address = input.next();

            Student std = new Student(name, address);
            StudentList.add(std);
        }

        for(Student std : StudentList){
            System.out.println(std.toString());
        }
     }
    }


   -------------------- Student Java File ----------------------
     public class Student {

       public String    name    = "";
       public String    address = "";

       public Student(String name2, String address2) {

           this.name = name2;
           this.address = address2;
       }

     @Override
     public String toString() {

         return "Student [name=" + this.name + ", address=" + this.address + "]";
        }

     }
```